# Enhance edges in OpenCV (Java) while removing noise

Tags: java, android, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to write an OpenCV program in Java that takes a photo of a marker with a phone and finds circular contours on the marker. I have gotten it working in the Android emulator (where the photo has perfect lighting conditions), but can't get it to work with the phone itself.
This is the marker I'm trying to capture:

[image]

After using the combination of transforming to grayscale, a Gaussian blur and a Canny edge detector, I get this output:

[image]

If I then try to find the contours on the image, the number of contours returned is really high (over 1000), but they aren't closed (because the edges seem to be too weak.
The contours drawn over the original image:

[image]

This is the code I use for the segmentation:

```
Mat processed = new Mat(original.height(), original.width(), original.type());

Imgproc.cvtColor(original, processed, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

Imgproc.GaussianBlur(processed, processed, new Size(7, 7), 0.1);

Imgproc.Canny(processed, processed,  50, 50*3, 3, false);
```

I have tried tweaking the different parameters (thresholds etc.), but feel like that isn't the ideal solution. I'm thinking there has to be a way to enhance the edges returned by the canny detector, but I haven't found anything myself.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this?

[image]

Noise is usually present - it can be reduced - you can distinguish the circles with adaptiveThreshold and then find the circles using the method I described below. The point is, the real-world image you get from the camera may contain a whole bunch of other circles - so it might be best to find all the circles. Compare them all in size. Find the 4 circles that are most similar to your marker in terms of color, size and placement.

A quick **python** code to distinguish the circles:

```py
# Make a gray version
gry = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Thresh
ada = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
    gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2
)

# Remove noises
out = cv2.medianBlur(ada, 7)

# Invert colors (Not needed)
out = ~out
```

I tested the Python code and it works; you can find an equivalent for Java or C++. I tried to explain the Java code but I wrote it on the fly and did not test it. The Java code I wrote probably has errors, but it does get the point. With a bit change will probably work. I also wrote the code that should find the circles as the last block. Working with it is tricky and requires adjusting the parameters.

**Java:**

```java
...
Imgproc.cvtColor(im, gry, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(gry, ada, 255, 
    Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);
Imgproc.medianBlur(ada, out, 7);
...
```

and for finding circles:
**Java:**

```java
...
SimpleBlobDetector_Params params = new SimpleBlobDetector_Params();
params.set_filterByCircularity(true);
params.set_minCircularity(0.01f);
params.set_maxArea(50000);//important
SimpleBlobDetector detector = SimpleBlobDetector.create(params);

// List of detected points 
MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
detector.detect(ada, keyPoints);

// Draw circles on final image
Scalar color = new Scalar(127, 0, 255);
for (KeyPoint key: keyPoints.toList()) {
    Imgproc.circle(im, key.pt, (int) (key.size / 2.0f), color, 3/*Thickness*/);
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It works in the emulator, however, it's quite hit or miss when taking photos with the phone. I had to tweak the circularity and maxArea (increase it), but the lighting conditions still have to be near perfect for it to detect the circles. Any ideas on how I could improve that?

Comment: You are welcome :) Take a look at OTSU for adaptiveThresholding.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into `dilation` operation in opencv to enhance the edges.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html

Also look into this example below with `Canny` edge detection, `approxPolyDP` and `minEnclosingCircle`. It is very close to your question.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1